# Use VisualCaptcha in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, captcha

Im trying to use [VisualCaptcha](https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha) with my Laravel apps. I have tried to adapt this [exemple](https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha-PHP/blob/master/app/app.php) with my code. But I dont know how to adapt this following callback to my controller :

```
$app->get( '/audio(/:type)', function( $type = 'mp3' ) use( $app ) {
    $captcha = new \visualCaptcha\Captcha( $app->session );

    if ( ! $captcha->streamAudio( $app->response, $type ) ) {
        $app->pass();
    }
} );
```

Here is my controller :

```
class CaptchaController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Start Captcha
     */
    public function start($params)
    {
        $session = new SessionCaptcha();
        $captcha = new Captcha($session);
        return $captcha->generate();
    }


    public function audio()
    {
        $session = new SessionCaptcha();
        $captcha = new Captcha($session);

        //$response = Response::make();
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        //return var_dump($response);
        return $captcha->streamAudio($response, 'mp3');
    }



}
```

The start function works but not the audio function... I dont know how to add the first parameter to "$captcha->streamAudio($firstParam, $extension)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case other people land here first, this has been answered at https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha-PHP/issues/16#issuecomment-53863330

The author mentioned not returning `$captcha->generate();` but also some undisclosed modifications.